# Rails Seralized My Object One Way & Refuses to Change

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization

I have a rails class that serializes one attribute.

> class Statistic < ActiveRecord::Base
>
> serialize :userlist
>
> end

When a statistic object is loaded and it's userlist changed from a String to an Array userlist always gets serialized back into a String. The framework seems to remember and deserialize :userlist into a String even if it went in as an Array.

```
>> s = Statistic.find 238
=> #<Statistic id: 238, userlist: "--- \n- 2222437\n- \"99779\"\n- \"120429\"\n- \"210503\"\n- 32...">
# Note here: :userlist is an Array in YAML. Why doesn't it get correctly deserialized?

>> s.userlist.class
=> String
>> s.userlist = s.userlist.split(/\s+/)

>> s.userlist.class
=> Array

>> s.save
=> true

>> s.reload
=> #<Statistic id: 238,userlist: "--- \n- 2222437\n- \"99779\"\n- \"120429\"\n- \"210503\"\n- 32...">

>> s.userlist.class
=> String
```

The goal of this exercise is to convert all String userlists to Array. **If I change the class (*serialize :userlist, Array*) before converting I get TypeMismatch exceptions.**

> ActiveRecord::SerializationTypeMismatch: userlist was supposed to be a Array, but was a String

**Is there a way to force AR to interpret userlist as an Array?**

```
% rails --version
Rails 2.3.4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. The String is not correct YAML:

```
>> YAML::load(s.userlist)
ArgumentError: syntax error:ScannerException while scanning a quoted scalar we had this found unexpected end of stream
        from (irb):8
```

The code from AR::B is

```
      def object_from_yaml(string)
        return string unless string.is_a?(String) && string =~ /^---/
        YAML::load(string) rescue string
      end
```

Some of the data were longer than 65,535 characters long, overflowing the mysql text column.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a particular reason you're not using a regular association for this?

To answer the question, IIRC you can pass the `class_name` to serialize.

```
serialize :userlist, :class_name => 'Array'
```

Alternatively try:

```
serialize :userlist, Array
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: serialize :userlist, Array is the proper syntax.

Comment: A regular association is unnecessarily heavy in this case.  I know how to make *new* records into arrays. If I change the class now the *existing* objects with String :userlist attributes throw exceptions.  The framework seems to remember and deserialize :userlist into a String even if it went in as an Array.